# How could Arjuna entered heaven with his physical body during exile?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, lokas, heaven, epics

As we all know Arjuna entered heaven at the Time of their Vanavas, how could he able to do that?

Comment: He was specially invited. Before that he had performed severe austerities and won the approval of Śiva, Indra and other devas. So, he was invited and Mātali, Indra's charioteer himself took him on the chariot. When he entered, Indra gave Arjuna the celestial sight to perceive Amarāvatī's divine beauty. It was invitation of a brief visit. In the Purāṇas and epics, it wasn't rare for that to happen, as r̥ṣis also temporarily visited the heavens and he had undergone quite a lot of asceticism, approval of devas and possessed the weapon of Śiva himself.

Comment: Other than this, Indra had the purpose of teaching him the use of some divine weapons as well, such as his own. Plus, it was only in heaven, that Arjuna learnt singing and dancing which proved useful for him in the 13th year of exile. And it was in heaven that he got a curse of being a eunuch for his 13th yr in exile which also became useful for him and was a good disguise for him. So, it was for purpose that he was invited and not for just fun. He was the chosen of the devas, in a way.
But he couldn't stay permanently there.